# use javascript function to sum of array of object

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have an array of object which looks like

```
const data = [{'id': '1'}, {marks: [{ subId: '2', "submarks" : [1,2,2,0,0]}, { subId: '2', "submarks" : [1,2,2,0,0]}, { subId: '3', "submarks" : [1,2,2,10,0]} ,{ subId: '4', "submarks" : [10,5,2,0,0]}] }]
```

Here, I am trying to get the sum of all the `submarks`.

In this case the output will be

```
42
```

I tried

```
const getTotal = () => {
 
 const marksArray = data['marks']
    
}
```

How do I get this ?

Comment: Is the object with the `marks` always the second item in the array? Or can the array contain multiple objects with the `marks` array?

Comment: It can at any place , name will not be same for other objects

Comment: You say you tried, but your attempt doesn't try to sum at all. It merely tries to retrieve a property called `marks`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `_.flatMap()` twice to get an array of all `summarks` and `_.sum()` them:

```js
const data = [{'id': '1'}, {marks: [{ subId: '2', "submarks" : [1,2,2,0,0]}, { subId: '2', "submarks" : [1,2,2,0,0]}, { subId: '3', "submarks" : [1,2,2,10,0]} ,{ subId: '4', "submarks" : [10,5,2,0,0]}] }]

const result = _.sum(_.flatMap(_.flatMap(data, 'marks'), 'submarks'))

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.20/lodash.min.js" integrity="sha512-90vH1Z83AJY9DmlWa8WkjkV79yfS2n2Oxhsi2dZbIv0nC4E6m5AbH8Nh156kkM7JePmqD6tcZsfad1ueoaovww==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can to like below. Assuming the marks object is always going to be in the 1st index as per your example data.

```js
const data = [{'id': '1'}, {marks: [{ subId: '2', "submarks" : [1,2,2,0,0]}, { subId: '2', "submarks" : [1,2,2,0,0]}, { subId: '3', "submarks" : [1,2,2,10,0]} ,{ subId: '4', "submarks" : [10,5,2,0,0]}] }]

const total = data[1].marks.reduce((total, obj) => {
  return total += obj.submarks.reduce((subTotal, mark) => {
    return subTotal += mark
  }, 0)
}, 0)


console.log(total)
```